# WebAssetmanager and Option weight

Tags: css

I have read the Joomla documentation https://docs.joomla.org/J4.x:Web_Assets.
I can't find the weight option there.

It is present in the Joomla code. For example, here: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/763dc9c35ac2d2e757bf9a4bbcad4ba3d988e755/templates/cassiopeia/joomla.asset.json#L47

What does it mean? Where can I find more information about this and other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a sorting mechanism for assets order. If you look inside `/libraries/src/WebAsset/WebAssetManager.php` you will find  `calculateOrderOfActiveAssets()` method that referring to [Kahn's_algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Kahn.27s_algorithm)

Unfortunately there is no official documentation about the `weight` option. Probably you can use it to set the ordering for assets, but that's only my assumption.